# @Value with singleton in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, singleton

I have a class ResourcesProperties.java

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
@Component
public class ResourcesProperties {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConf() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    public static ResourcesProperties instance;

    @Bean
    public static ResourcesProperties getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new ResourcesProperties();
        return instance;
    }

    @Getter
    @Value("${room.rightStatusRoom}")
    private static boolean rightStatusRoom;

    @Getter
    @Value("${room.countGuests}")
    private static int countGuests;
}
```

There is a "config.properties" property file

```
room.rightStatusRoom=true
room.countGuests=101
```

Why, when accessing the of fields with @Value annotation, they don't return the specified values from property file?

Example:

```
if(ResourcesProperties.getInstance().isRightStatusRoom()) { //returned false instead true
    //business-logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
@Component
public class ResourcesProperties {

    @Getter
    @Value("${room.rightStatusRoom}")
    private boolean rightStatusRoom;

    @Getter
    @Value("${room.countGuests}")
    private int countGuests;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring doesn't allow to inject value into a static object.
So you have 2 options, get rid of the static or call a non-static setter that sets the static variable.
More info can be found here: https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-inject-a-value-into-static-variables/

So these are the solutions. 
Solution 1:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
@Component
public class ResourcesProperties {

    @Getter
    @Value("${room.rightStatusRoom}")
    private boolean rightStatusRoom;

    @Getter
    @Value("${room.countGuests}")
    private int countGuests;
}
```

Solution 2:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
@Component
public class ResourcesProperties {

    @Getter
    private static boolean rightStatusRoom;

    @Getter
    private static int countGuests;

    @Value("${room.rightStatusRoom}")
    public void setRightStatusRoom(boolean rightStatusRoom) {
        this.rightStatusRoom = rightStatusRoom
    }

    @Value("${room.countGuests}")
    public void setCountGuests(int countGuests) {
        this.countGuests = countGuests
    }
}
```